# jQuery - run a function after .prop()

Tags: jquery

Several jQuery functions take a function argument that will run after the function is done(and therefore only if the selector the function is run on matched anything), but not all. What I want to do is select the correct radio button (based on a key/value pair within an .each() iteration) and then show the div whose ID matches the value.

The context is I'm populating a form based on a JSON-formatted array, iterating through each pair.

Here's the snippet:

```
$('input:radio[name="' + key + '"][value="'+ value + '"]')
     .prop('checked', true);    
}); // this works
```

I then want to run this line:

```
$('#' + value).show();
```

only if the first selector matched anything.

I'm sure there's a simple way to do this, but I don't know it.

Comment: The callback functions you mention are not for the purpose you're using them for. They are a function of *asynchronous* code, their purpose is not to run conditionally if a selector matches. Your code is not asynchronous, you need a simple `if` statement.

Comment: Good info, meagar, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm thinking you could you just break it up. Have a variable that contains the results of the selector. If that array contains any matches (check its length), then set the checked property to true and show the other element:

```
var $matches = $('input:radio[name="' + key + '"][value="'+ value + '"]');
if ($matches.length) {
    $matches.prop('checked', true);
    $('#' + value).show();
}
```

If you're running that multiple times, simply wrap it up in a function that takes the `key` and `value` as parameters.

**EDIT**: You could shorten it up a bit:

```
var $matches = $('input:radio[name="' + key + '"][value="'+ value + '"]').prop('checked', true);
$('#' + value).toggle($matches.length);
```

This example also takes care of hiding the other element if there are no matches.

Comment: I suppose that works, though I was hoping there was a cleaner way to do it, like `myVar.prop(checked, true, function(){/*do stuff*/}` - the way animation functions do, though I know this wouldn't work exactly.

Comment: The thing is that `prop` doesn't really care if there are any matches or not. It will attempt to set the property on each one whether it finds 0 or a million. It would be odd to think that it would ever need a callback.

Comment: I see, so regardless of how many matches the selector finds, `prop()` will still run?

Comment: @mindlesscomposer: Well, jQuery's probably smart enough to bail out early if when there are no matches, but the intent is that it will run on anything it *does match*. Most jQuery functions run on all matched elements, and some only run on the first (e.g. `.val()` will return the value of the first match only, but `.val('sample')` will set the value on *all* matches). I would consult the documentation when you are unsure. In general, understand that the result of `$('selector')` is *always* an array, whether it has 0, 1, or many elements.